# Spark Standalone cluster only two workers utilized

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0, spark-submit, apache-spark-standalone

In Spark Standalone Cluster, only 2 of the 6 worker instances get utilized, rest of them are idle. I used two VMs both having 4 cores. 2 workers were on the local VM(where master was started) and 4 workers were on the other VM. Only local two got utilized. I also tried running it with 4 non local workers, even then only 2 of them got utilized. What should I do?

This is the spark-submit command:-

./spark-submit --master spark://10.234.17.101:7077 --class com.emc.pluto.rca.engine.Server --jars /root/rt.jar, /root/ashwin/spark-core_2.10-2.2.0.jar I have specified the worker instances and memory in spark-env.sh –

Comment: Please provide the spark submit command

Comment: ./spark-submit --master spark://10.234.17.101:7077 --class com.emc.pluto.rca.engine.Server --jars /root/rt.jar, /root/ashwin/spark-core_2.10-2.2.0.jar
I have specified the worker instances and memory in spark-env.sh

Comment: Did you try Yarn? Or Just by specifying the workers in the submit command, do you see any change?

Comment: No, I haven't tried yarn yet. How to specify number of worker instances in spark-submit in standalone mode?

Comment: Is there enough work to do amongst all executors? There's a configuration property for setting that number. It's in the  documentation

Comment: Yes, there were 1000 partitions and i was transforming rdd using its "foreach" method. I could only find command for setting worker instances in standalone mode.